# Geometry question on ratios

Tags: geometry

In an acute triangle ABC, points D, E, F are located on the sides BC, CA, AB respectively such that CD/CE = CA/CB , AE/AF = AB/AC , BF/BD = BC/BA . how to  prove that AD, BE, CF are the altitudes of ABC.

Comment: try  to prove A,B,D,F in one circle, and see what is the next result.

Comment: Will you plz explain it on screen?

Comment: @Ayush, Will you please draw a picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the given ratios serves as the condition for “the converse of the power of a point”. Therefore, for example, the converse of the power of point C yields a circle (in red) passing through A, B, D, E. The green and the blue circles can be similarly formed.

Another fact needed is "With respect to 3 intersecting circles, the 3 common chords are concurrent at the radical center". This can be proved by considering the powers with respect to each circles. Thus, AD, BE and CF intersect at H.

[image]

[Note that $CHF$ is a straight line and Please ignore the black line being dotted. The dotted line comes from an old drawing which I am too lazy to replace.]

From the green circle, $\alpha = \beta$

From the red circle, $\beta = \gamma$

This means $C, E, H, D$ are con-cyclic. That is, the purple broken line is a circle.

[image]

From the purple circle, $\theta = \phi$

From the red circle, $\phi = \omega$

This means $\theta = \omega = 90^0$ implying $AD$ is an altitude. The other 2 altitudes can be found in the similar fashion.

Comment: from which software u created this diagram

Comment: @Ayush Using Geogebra to sketch the draft. Save it to the clipboard. Copy it to WORD for re-sizing. Send the resultant to Paintbrush for the finishing touch. Upload it finally.

Comment: From the purple circle,  θ=ϕ plz explain

Comment: After proving that C, E, H, D are con-cyclic, CEHD is the a cyclic quadrilateral.  ϕ happens to be the exterior angle of that quadrilateral and θ the interior opposite angle. They are therefore equal.

Comment: @Ayush See above.

Comment: see above means

Comment: @Ayush I made the explanation but forgot to address the comment to you.